# in RStudio given a package and addin name, get the function that is called

Tags: r, rstudio, add-in, rstudioapi

Here are some of my addins :

[image]

For example, I'd like to know **programmatically** what function is called by "reprex" for the addin "Reprex selection".

If I go to the repo and browse to "reprex/inst/rstudio/addins.dcf" I can see that it is `reprex:::reprex_selection()`.

So I wish to have :

```
magic("reprex", "Reprex selection")
# [1] "reprex_selection"
```

Returning the function without naming it would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read that `addins.dcf` file with `read.dcf()`:

```r
magic <- function(package, name) {
  addins <- read.dcf(system.file("rstudio/addins.dcf", package = package))
  with(as.data.frame(addins), Binding[Name == name])
}
magic("reprex", "Reprex selection")
#> [1] "reprex_selection"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>